# Silo data for users into particular physical location

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We have a system we're designing which has to hold data for people globally, including countries with very strict data protection policies, specifically where data about its citizens must physically reside that country.

Now we could engineer a mechanism for silo-ing/querying the data where it must be pulled from a particular location but as the system will be azure based, we were hoping that cosmosDB's partitioning feature might be an option.

Based on the information available to date for [partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data), it seems like it's possible to assign a location-specific partition for some data but it's not very clear. Any search for partitioning in general goes on about high availability and low latency - good things - but not what I'm looking for.

To this end, can location-specific data be assigned in cosmosDB as part of its feature set or is this something that has to be engineered on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data sovereignty, you must engineer a data access layer across multiple Cosmos DB accounts. Cosmos DB by default will replicate your data across all regions within your account (which is not what you need).

While not specifically for this scenario, you can see a description of how to build such a layer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/multi-region-writers